# Convert a column with a list of dicts, where column name and value are both present as values inside dict keys

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

This question is different from the other ones because in none of them the column name resides in the value of a key... Please look at the examples given before marking as duplicate.

I have a df like so:

```py
df: col1 col2 col3
    100  200  [{'attribute': 'Pattern', 'value': 'Printed'},...
```

Closer look at column 3 looks like:

```py
[{'attribute': 'Pattern', 'value': 'Printed'},
 {'attribute': 'Topwear style', 'value': 'T shirt'},
 {'attribute': 'Bottomwear Length', 'value': 'Short'},
 {'attribute': 'Colour Palette', 'value': 'Bright colours'},
 {'attribute': 'Bottomwear style', 'value': 'Baggy'},
 {'attribute': 'Topwear length', 'value': 'Waist'},
 {'attribute': 'Sleeve style', 'value': 'Sleeveless'},
 {'attribute': 'Type of pattern', 'value': 'Graphic print'},
 {'attribute': 'Neck', 'value': 'Round'},
 {'attribute': 'Level of embellishment', 'value': 'No'}]
```

Where each attribute is column name and each value, is the value for that column name.

The output will look something like this:

```py
df: col1   col2    Pattern       Topwear Style       Bottomwear Length ....
    100    200     Printed       T shirt             Shorts
```

There are multiple rows with repeating and new attributes and values.
How would I go about doing this in pandas? I tried searching for something similar but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Nope, that's why I had to post it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
df=df.join(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v).set_index('attribute').T 
               for v in df.pop('col3')]).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Setup:

```
d=[{'attribute': 'Pattern', 'value': 'Printed'},
 {'attribute': 'Topwear style', 'value': 'T shirt'},
 {'attribute': 'Bottomwear Length', 'value': 'Short'},
 {'attribute': 'Colour Palette', 'value': 'Bright colours'},
 {'attribute': 'Bottomwear style', 'value': 'Baggy'},
 {'attribute': 'Topwear length', 'value': 'Waist'},
 {'attribute': 'Sleeve style', 'value': 'Sleeveless'},
 {'attribute': 'Type of pattern', 'value': 'Graphic print'},
 {'attribute': 'Neck', 'value': 'Round'},
 {'attribute': 'Level of embellishment', 'value': 'No'}]
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':100,'b':200,'col3':[d]},index=[0])
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
x = df['col3'].tolist()
newcol = {item['attribute'] : [item['value']] for item in x }
newdf = pd.DataFrame(newcol)
del df['col3'] 
print(df.join(newdf, how='right'))
```

Output

```
   col1  col2  Pattern Topwear style Bottomwear Length  Colour Palette  \
0   100   200  Printed       T shirt             Short  Bright colours  
...
```

---

dataframe for test.

```
data = {'col1':100, 'col2': 200, 'col3': [{'attribute': 'Pattern', 'value': 'Printed'},
 {'attribute': 'Topwear style', 'value': 'T shirt'},
 {'attribute': 'Bottomwear Length', 'value': 'Short'},
 {'attribute': 'Colour Palette', 'value': 'Bright colours'},
 {'attribute': 'Bottomwear style', 'value': 'Baggy'},
 {'attribute': 'Topwear length', 'value': 'Waist'},
 {'attribute': 'Sleeve style', 'value': 'Sleeveless'},
 {'attribute': 'Type of pattern', 'value': 'Graphic print'},
 {'attribute': 'Neck', 'value': 'Round'},
 {'attribute': 'Level of embellishment', 'value': 'No'}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: @jezrael sure, check the updation.

Comment: ya, problem of answer is different format like OP, so failed for OP data.

Comment: Your solution is definitely easier to understand for a pandas newbie like me.

Comment: Nope, easy as well, thanks for your answer, upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested list comprehension with dict comprehension for list of dictionaries possible pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

Advatage is better performance, disadvatage a bit complicated.

```
d = [{'attribute': 'Pattern', 'value': 'Printed'},
 {'attribute': 'Topwear style', 'value': 'T shirt'},
 {'attribute': 'Bottomwear Length', 'value': 'Short'},
 {'attribute': 'Colour Palette', 'value': 'Bright colours'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[100, 20], 'col2':[200, 10], 'col3':[d, d]})
print (df)

   col1  col2                                               col3
0   100   200  [{'attribute': 'Pattern', 'value': 'Printed'},...
1    20    10  [{'attribute': 'Pattern', 'value': 'Printed'},...

a = [{y['attribute']: y['value']  for y in x for k, v in y.items()} for x in df.pop('col3')]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(a))
print (df)
   col1  col2  Pattern Topwear style Bottomwear Length  Colour Palette
0   100   200  Printed       T shirt             Short  Bright colours
1    20    10  Printed       T shirt             Short  Bright colours
```

Comment: Why are you even doing the for k, v in y.tems() part ?

Comment: @piyushdaga - because it is flattenting, similar idea like for list from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: @piyushdaga - it is not necesarry here, because is used `y['attribute']: y['value']`